# When is an activity forcefully recreated?

Tags: android, android-activity

The Android docs say that configuration changes can force an activity to be recreated, the most common change being a rotation. Now, there are some methods that can determine whether an activity is being destroyed to be recreated but all(?) of these methods are called after `onStop()` and aren't guaranteed or recommended for data saving purposes.

To give an example, there is an EditText activity which autosaves what they have written/updated if the user navigates away from the app via back button, app switch, e.t.c. However, the user might not want to save their changes when there is a configuration change so I need to be prepared for those cases.

Comment: You should never lose user's data on purpose.

Comment: On top of @ianhanniballake's contribution, I would say it sounds like you're over-engineering for a case that may not even exist.

Comment: what exactly you wanted to know? to save or not to save activity state?

Comment: Its upto you to decide which fields will be saved and which won't be saved in case of a configuration change.  I have not seen an app that allows their user to decide this.

Comment: @ianhanniballake What do you mean by that? You're saying I should save the data even if they don't want me to as opposed to losing the data when they did want it saved?

Comment: @Lobstw - yes, if you have an auto-save, it should always auto-save. It seems like what you actually need is to save the original value for use with your cancel/revert button.

Answer (score 0):

When an activity is destroyed by the system because of configuration change onSaveInstanceState is called.

```
 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {            
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }
```

Store data that you want to persist in outState bundle.

Then you'll receive the stored data in onCreate and onRestoreInstanceState.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Use it to retrieve data you had stored in onSaveInstanceState earlier.

Comment: Scenario: I have "auto-save" on but the user does not want to save their input. `onSaveInstanceState` is called between `onPause` and `onStop`. And because data saving should happen in `onPause`, I would have saved the data already by the time I can deal with a configuration change, correct?

Answer (score 0):

By default System saves the state of few widgets (EditText , TextView) on it's own and this magic happens in `super.onSaveInstanceState()`.

`@Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }`

So if you do not want to save the text in EditText , just do `editText.setText("")` before calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()`.

Hope this helps.